# Multipart request through Android - Node.js

Tags: android, node.js

I am trying a send an image from android to node server. What I did:

```
        try{
            //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName) );
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
            dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image_upload\";originalFilename=\"" + params[1] + "\";path=\"" + params[0] + "\"" + lineEnd); // originalFilename is the Name of the File to be uploaded
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }
```

I am getting `image_upload` file parameters in node as `files.image_upload[0].originalFilename` and `files.image_upload[0].path`

Problem is happening at `image_upload[0]`. Server crashes saying 
`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: It would really help if you could state the reason of downvote so that I can improve my next questions.

Answer (score 0):

Give mime type to your image path file.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced a part of code to this and it's working now.

```
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image_upload\"; filename=\""+params[1]+"\""+lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: \"undefined\""+lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```